# Running PHP scripts in the background

Tags: php, shell, exec, multiprocessing, background-process

So I was wondering if there's a better way to do this in 2013.

Older answers suggest something like this

```
shell_exec('nohup php script.php some_argument another_argument > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Which seems to work, but it looks weird. And the thing is that I don't have much control over the script I execute. For example I would like the possibility to terminate it inside another request. The only solution I found is to place a file somewhere, like "exit_now.txt', then inside that script check if that file exists and fire `exit()` if it does.

Comment: Use a job server, such as Gearman, and with supervisord restarting your worker script.

Answer (score 0):

You can send signal to the invoked process (by `kill` command from shell) and install signal handler to your program to react as you wish.

[Documentation for installing signal handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php)

[Example with pcntl_fork() and pcntl_signal()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.example.php)